# Get Main Domain from Domain String

Tags: php, string

I've a string like `third.second.tld` or `fourth.third.second.tld` in php. What is the simplest and best way to extract the main domain name (second.tld)?

I tried this

```
 $domain = 'fourth.third.second.tld';
 $topLevel = array_reverse(explode('.', $domain))[0];
 $secondLevel = array_reverse(explode('.', $domain))[1];
 $mainDomain = $secondLevel . '.' . $topLevel;
```

but I think it's a bit complicated. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Multiple `explode()`s and `array_reverse()`s can be expensive. Save the explode and reverse into a variable and then access the `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, etc...

Comment: split once and `array_pop` twice and finally implode, or regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could use regex

```
$a = 'fourth.third.second.tld';
$b = 'third.second.tld';
$c = 'second.tld';

function getDomainName($str) {
    $r = preg_replace('/(\w*)(\.)(\w*)$/', '', $str);
    return str_replace($r, '', $str);
}

echo getDomainName($a);

echo "\n";

echo getDomainName($b);

echo "\n";

echo getDomainName($c);
```

the result will be

```
second.tld
second.tld
second.tld
```

[php sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/acb5aa6527755c884d71fc4c37abd40f1676a080)

Comment: How does it work on `$a = 'max.möhres.söhne.tld'; $b = 'xn--shne-5qa.tld';$c = 'my-domain.tld'`?

Comment: If you can read regex, It’s pretty straight forward - it gets “wordDOTword” from the end of the string

Comment: I can read regex. Try my example data. As a better approximation you should use `[^.]` instead of the word-character. The latter matches identifiers of many programming languages.

Comment: well and then there is the problem with domainnames like example.com.au. imagine someone has registered the domain "com.au" and makes a subdomain. it is called "images.com.au". and then there is another guy that registered "images.com.au". how do you find out the real host and tld/sld.

Comment: Now this is helpful comment, providing helpful comment/answer is always good way to start convo

Comment: @Bernhard Good point as well, even if it is a definition problem. Technically `com` is the SLD in this case, but we consider `example.com.au` to be the domain of `www.example.com.au`.

Answer (score 2):

It is more complicated than you think - do use a library specifically built for such operations. Otherwise, you may discover the various pitfalls of different TLDs. For example, in .com-domains, the second level is usually the "main domain", but users in the UK are used to .co.uk-domains where the "main domain" is found at the 3rd level.

https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract is one of those libraries built for PHP and the README starts with an example to extract and split TLD, "main domain" and subdomains from each other. TLDExtract does also support IDNA-encoded domains (internationalized domain names).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. (+1) Only in rare cases where we know the possible input data (fix input table that will never change) we may rely on a simple implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$domain = 'fourth.third.second.tld';

$parts = explode(".", $domain);

$lastParts = array_slice($parts, -2);

$mainDomain = join(".", $lastParts);

//output: second.tld
```